# Parsing Double Quotes within JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to parse some JSON I'm receiving from a third-party API. The problem is that some of the JSON has quotes inside quotes, like this:

```
var json = '{"sentence": "My favorite sport is "dodgeball"." }';
```

I'm pretty sure the browser is interpreting the quote as

```
"My favorite sport is"
```

and then hitting an syntax error on the following characters. How do I avoid this?

**Edit:** I posted a simplified version of the problem, but here is the actual snippet of code that is giving me trouble (the problem is "*Cool Vendor*" wrapped in quotes):

```
{"content":"Vana Workforce is the Cloud HR Company. We are a global provider of human capital software and service solutions specifically designed to the needs of small and medium enterprises delivered on-demand.

Developed on the industry's leading cloud platform Force.com, Vana Human Capital Management delivers one complete and integrated human capital management solution for global organizations form hire to retire including the core human resource system of record, benefits & compensation, absence management, performance and talent management, career and succession planning, workforce collaboration, and workforce analytics.

Founded in 2008, Vana Workforce has offices in Canada and the United States with customers on every continent, and was recently recognized by Gartner Research as a "Cool Vendor" for 2010.","val":"Description"}
```

Comment: That JSON is invalid. He exactly are you getting it from the API?

Comment: I'm pulling a list of users, and the short bio section sometimes contains double quotes in it. Sadly, the service (zoho.com) does not sanitize it.

Comment: It's not an issue of "sanitization"; it's simply erroneous. If you fed that to a JSON parser, in other words, it would just throw an exception. Since you're not doing that, then what are you doing?

Comment: I'm receiving the erroneous JSON from a third-party API, and I was trying to fix it so I could feed it to a JSON parser.

Comment: OK, whatever. All I was asking was to see **exactly** what comes back from the API, raw and untouched. What you posted is a snipped of JavaScript code, which is almost certainly not what's returned from Zoho.

Comment: @Pointy I added the true JSON code which is giving me trouble.

Comment: Well if that's actually what's coming directly back from the API, it's a bug on their side, and a pretty amazing one. JSON is an extremely simple format to construct, and every common server framework  has well-tested tools to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not valid JSON, so you cannot do it with standard methods.

You either have to escape the quotes like this: `"sport is \" "` or else you need to write your own sanitizer

Comment: How would I sanitize the code (only escaping the characters inside the values)?

Comment: You would have to inspect the string and if you see a pattern replace the " with \". If this occurs randomly then I don't think you can't do it automatically and you need to sanitize it manually (or fix the service that is given you the pseudo-json)

Comment: @jarednielsen you can't really sanitize it; it's syntactically incorrect.  It should be produced correctly in the first place by the service that creates it.

Comment: Exactly, it can only be done if there's a pattern, for example it's always preceded by the same sentence. If that's the case you could replace the sentence with an escaped one. But as I said, better to get it right from the service in the first place

Answer (score 1):

Those quotes should be escaped -

```
"My favorite sport is \"dodgeball\"."
```

If it's a real service (not homework) this will be done properly.  If it's homework, then go fix that bug in the service.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? The real JSON response is very long, and I can't manually escape every single quote.

Comment: @jarednielsen If the service is actually broken in this way then don't use it.

Comment: Okay. Would using XML avoid this problem?

Comment: @jarednielsen I have no idea what you are talking about.  Do you own the service that is buggy?  Or does someone else?  Does it support XML as well as JSON?

Comment: Someone else owns the buggy source. It supports both XML and JSON formats, so I could get XML data rather than JSON, if needed.

Comment: @jarednielsen if their XML implementation isn't buggy, then that will work.