# Double quotes issue with parse json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

We have an issue in passing JSON , the value contains double quotes and we are getting error

```
"searchResultsDetails":[
{
"compannyName":""schiing" Immobien & Co Lingasse KG",
"testId":77472,
}
]
```

You can see that the compannyName contains double quotes in the value.

```
var data= $.parseJSON(modelAttr);
```

modelattr is the above JSON string,

when I try this jquery method, I am getting parsing error, how we can parse double quotes and special characters, please help

Regards
Hari

Comment: You have to escape them using \. Like this `"compannyName":"\"schiing\" Immobien & Co Lingasse KG"`.

Comment: Possible Dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16179082/parsing-double-quotes-within-json

Comment: Could you please tell me how we can achieve this in Javascript/jquery

Comment: You have to ensure that the values in the JSON are properly escaped. Since I don't know where you get your values from (hardcoded, db, etc.) I can't answer that for you.

Comment: The values are getting from JAVA server layer using jackson parsor

Comment: How is `modelAttr` initialized? How do you load the data?

Comment: Just look how SO color your JSON `schiing` is not a string so it's invalid JSON.

Answer (score 3):

To write special characters in a string you have to escape them, using the backslash character `\`.

So your example would look like this:

`"compannyName":"\"schiing\" Immobien & Co Lingasse KG"`

Comment: Could you please tell me how we can achieve this in Javascript/jquery

Comment: Where are you getting the JSON values from?

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732409/how-can-i-put-double-quotes-inside-a-string-within-an-ajax-json-response-from-ph ........................ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21070173/android-parsing-json-string-inside-of-double-quotes ....... http://www.2ality.com/2012/09/javascript-quotes.html